# How I use validation with out form element

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs

how can I do an angular validation for a specific input, div or area, without giving a form name.

```
<form name = 'form'>
    <input name = 'userId'>
    <tt ng-show="form.userId.$error'>There's something wrong</tt>
</form>
```

can I do

```
<input name = 'userId'>
<tt ng-show="userId.$error'>There's something wrong</tt>
```

to get rid of the form.
and I do this b/c I might need one single input field that I dont want to attach form element and name to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ng-form`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angForm) if you do not want to use an actual `<form/>` element.

```
<ng-form name="angularForm">
    <input name='userId'/>
    <tt ng-show="angularForm.userId.$error">There's something wrong</tt>
</ng-form>
```

Some Notes:

- If you want validation `ngModel` is required
- You probably want to use `angularForm.userId.$valid` (or `$invalid`) as `$error` will always show up as it is an object

**[Working Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Gwx5P/)**

```
<ng-form name="angularForm">
    <input name='userId' required="required" ng-model="someText" /> 
    <tt ng-hide="angularForm.userId.$valid">There's something wrong</tt>
    {{angularForm.userId.$error}}
</ng-form>
```

Comment: could i use ng-form inside the input to make it one line?